# How To Handle and Propagate Exception in 3 tier architecture using C#

Tags: c#, exception, n-tier-architecture

**I am creating a C# web application using 3 tier architecture.**

Can any one suggest that , What is the best way to handle Exception in 3 tier architecture and how can I propagate my Exception from DAL and BLL to Presentation Layer.

Below mentioned is what I am trying now

```
namespace DataAccessLogic
{
    public class DataAccessException : ApplicationException
    {
        public DataAccessException()
        {
        }
        public DataAccessException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

        protected DataAccessException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context)
        {
        }

        public DataAccessException(string message, Exception innerException)
            :base(message, innerException)
        {
        }
    }
    public class BankTransactionDataAccess
    {
        public void GetAssociateDEtails(string associateID)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "testdev";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_kk", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new DataAccessException("Unable to connect DataBase", ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In case of your presentation layer, who is creating the layer? your business logic layer? (Could you please explain, the flow of your 3 tire architecture a bit?)

Comment: Ugghhhh... Your bigger problem is that you are trapping exceptions using `catch (Exception ex)`. That's a recipe for making your code buggy and very difficult to manage and maintain. You should very very very rarely ever catch an `Exception`. You should be catching specific exceptions that you know can occur and that you can properly handle. Otherwise you should just let them bubble up.

Comment: Code snippet is for JS / HTML / CSS. It is not for C#.

Comment: Create a library for exceptions (reference it in your different layers) , handle the exception in your global.ascx or in generic handler for exception, let the exception bubble up as specified by @Enigmativity.